# No "sqlread" in Matlab 2019a Database Toolbox?

Tags: mysql, matlab, database-connection

Our shop just upgraded to Matlab 2019a, and I'm bumbling around the import of MySQL/MariaDB data (`*.frm` files).  I found myself to the [`sqlread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/import-data-from-database-table-using-sqlread-function.html) tutorial.  I have yet to fully plumb the machinations behind the `database` command to set up a connection, but in messing around, I seem to have discovered that I don't have an `sqlread` function.  This is odd, as I have the Database Toolbox:

```
>> ver
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MATLAB Version: 9.6.0.1072779 (R2019a)
MATLAB License Number: ______
Operating System: Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise  Version 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
Java Version: Java 1.8.0_181-b13 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MATLAB                                                Version 9.6         (R2019a)
Database Toolbox                                      Version 9.1         (R2019a)
    <...snip...>

>> help sqlread
--- sqlread not found. Showing help for stlread instead. ---
    <...snip...>

>> which database
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\toolbox\database\database\database.m

>> which sqlread
'sqlread' not found.
```

Why would this not be available?

Comment: You should ask MATLAB customer support.

Comment: That's my next move. I wanted to rule out something obvious that was either fixable, and whether it was normal (for some reason unknown to me)

Answer (score 0):

TMW investigated and reported that `sqlread` becomes available after setting up a data source.

Unfortunately, the next road block that I'm confronting is [setting up the data source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56014583/how-to-set-up-windows-7-odbc-data-source-for-cygwins-mysql).

My question about a simpler alternative to import MySQL data into Matlab still stands.

Thanks.